# Branding the "Authorize access" button for a unverified Gmail add-on app?

Tags: gmail-addons

So, I am trying to get my Gmail add-on approved by Google and I am struggling with one last thing.

My app use "sensitive" scopes (such as `gmail.addons.current.message.readonly`) and therefore the user needs to authorize that my app is allowed to do that. For apps that haven't yet been approved by Google, the user is prompted with an "Authorize access" button (see [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MweLM.png) and this link https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/authorizing-addons#authorizing_unpublished_g_suite_add-ons).

Now, I have received feedback from the OAuth Verification Dev Team at Google that I have to change this button to the Google brand guidelines. My problem with this is that the screen that needs to be changed is a default Gmail Authorization screen (for unverified apps only) and I dont know how to change that...

Does anyone have any idea how to proceed? I have emailed the OAuth devs mutiple times, but they dont provide me with any pointers, only threats that my app will be rejected if I don't comply.

UPDATE: The full response from the Google team below:

*Thank you for your response.*

*Please note, that since the 'Authorize Access' button initiates the OAuth Sign-in process it is subject to comply with the [Google sign-in branding guidelines](https://developers.google.com/identity/branding-guidelines#top_of_page).*

- *You may refer to Figure 2: Unverified app authorization flow on our
  [OAuth Client Verification page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/client-verification), which showcases the full OAuth
  Sign-in process.*

***Google Sign-in Branding***

*In order to proceed with the [sensitive scope verification](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914#verification-types) for the project: xxx-xxx, please update the previously flagged Google sign-in button so that it complies with the Google sign-in branding guidelines.*

*Please reply to this email once you have made the appropriate updates to your site and/or your OAuth Consent Screen so that we may continue with the verification process.*

- ***Note:*** Failure to satisfy/provide the preceding information might
  result in a rejection of your request. To avoid this outcome, update
  the applicable information in your request to meet our requirements.

Comment: What is the exact formulation of the Google feedback?

Comment: I have updated the original post with the full response I got from the Google team.

Comment: The [guidelines](https://developers.google.com/identity/branding-guidelines#top_of_page) you linked suggest that the sign-in button has to say "Sign-in with Google" and meet the other requirements explained in thsi documentaiton.

Comment: I don't think that you have read my post thoroughly... My problem is that I don't know how to change that button as it is a default Google page as far as I understand it.